# Reading lines from a file redirected to stdin in multiple processes using fgets

Tags: c, unix, process, io

I'm trying to make a c program that creates several processes, based on an argument, and then has them all start reading lines from stdin and then do things with them (for now I'm just printing them to the screen). Ideally, I would be able to redirect the input to a file when I run it, like so: `./a.out 3 < batchcmds`. With my current code, everything runs as expected (as far as I can tell) when I type in the input manually, but when I redirect input to my file `batchcmds`, it only reads the first line, then reads in gibberish.

```
~$ ./a.out 3 < batchcmds 
Main process 35e2e2
p35e2e2: Created child process 35e2e3
p35e2e3: Created child process 35e2e4
p35e2e4: Created child process 35e2e5
p35e2e2: Read ./testprog 1 2

p35e2e3: Read 0:��t
p35e2e5: Read 0:��t
p35e2e4: Read 0:��t
```

Here's my code:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define BUFFERSIZE 1024

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
        // reads argument
        int maxpc = atoi(argv[1]);

        // creates children
        printf("Main process %x\n", getpid());
        pid_t pid = 0;
        for(int pc = 0; pc < maxpc && pid == 0; pc++) {
                pid = fork();
                if(pid != 0) printf("p%x: Created child process %x\n", getpid(), pid);
        }

        // reads lines and prints
        char command[BUFFERSIZE];
        fgets(command, BUFFERSIZE, stdin);
        printf("p%x: Read %s\n", getpid(), command);

        // closes
        wait(NULL);
        exit(0);
}
```

Here's my input file `batchcmds`:

```
./testprog 1 2
./testprog 3 1
./testprog 2 2
./testprog 1 1
./testprog 2 1
./testprog 1 3
./testprog 2 3
```

I've looked all over and can't find any problems similar to this. I'm relatively new to both UNIX and C (I'm used to C++), so I suspect I'm missing something basic about i/o. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is a race condition during reading files with multiple processes in your code. The garbled output of the program is due to the uninitialized buffer and fgets not getting any data. If you insist on using multiple processes to read one file, you need to use file locking. I suggest having the main program read the file and then distribute data to multiple child processes through pipes. Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define BUFFERSIZE 1024

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    bool eof = false;
    char command[BUFFERSIZE];

    int (*pipes)[2] = NULL;

    fd_set fdset;

    // read argument
    int maxpc = argc > 1 ? atoi(argv[1]) : 0;

    if (maxpc == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s n\n", argv[0]);
        return 0;
    }

    //printf("Main Process %x\n", getpid());

    // malloc an array of file descriptors
    pipes = malloc(sizeof(*pipes) * maxpc);
    if (pipes == NULL)
    {
        perror("malloc");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // create children
    for (int pc = 0; pc < maxpc; pc++) {
        pid_t pid;

        if (pipe(pipes[pc]) == -1) {
            perror("pipe");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        pid = fork();
        if (pid == 0) { // child process
            FILE *file = NULL;

            close(pipes[pc][1]);

            //printf("Child Process %x\n", getpid());

            file = fdopen(pipes[pc][0], "r");

            while (fgets(command, sizeof(command), file) != NULL) {
                printf("p%x: Read %s", getpid(), command);
                for (unsigned int count = 10000000; count; --count); // do something
            }

            fclose(file);
            free(pipes);

            //printf("Child Process %x exit\n", getpid());

            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        } else if (pid < 0) { // fork failed
            perror("fork");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        } else {
            close(pipes[pc][0]);
        }
    }

    while (!eof) {
        int maxfd = -1;
        FD_ZERO(&fdset);

        for (int i = 0; i < maxpc; ++i) {
            FD_SET(pipes[i][1], &fdset);
            if (pipes[i][1] > maxfd) {
                maxfd = pipes[i][1];
            }
        }

        if (select(maxfd + 1, NULL, &fdset, NULL, NULL) == -1) {
            perror("select");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < maxpc; ++i) {
                if (FD_ISSET(pipes[i][1], &fdset)) {
                    if (fgets(command, sizeof(command), stdin) == NULL) {
                        eof = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    write(pipes[i][1], command, strlen(command));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (int pc = 0; pc < maxpc; pc++) {
        close(pipes[pc][1]);
    }

    while (wait(NULL) > 0); // wait for all child processes to finish

    //printf("Main process %x exit\n", getpid());

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
p9bd0: Read ./testprog 1 2
p9bd2: Read ./testprog 2 2
p9bd1: Read ./testprog 3 1
p9bd0: Read ./testprog 1 1
p9bd2: Read ./testprog 1 3
p9bd1: Read ./testprog 2 1
p9bd0: Read ./testprog 2 3
```

Comment: Thank you, that explains why my code worked when I changed it so that the parent process was reading the input.

Comment: Thanks for your acknowledgment. But I wonder what changes make your code work. If you don't deal with the race condition properly, like using locks or avoiding races, a probability error will be left.